# JBPM5 Building with maven

Tags: jbpm

I m trying to build JBPM5 in fedora 14 with this command ..

[user@localhost jbpm 5] mvn -DskipTests -DDocumentation install assembly:assembly deploy

I am using jbpm-5.0.0-src.zip from jbpm official website , jdk 1.5 , ant 1.7.1 , and maven 2.2.1.I am getting following problem.....

[WARNING] Assembly file: /home/user/jbpm5/target/jbpm-5.0.0-pre-bin is not a regular file (it may be a directory). It cannot be attached to the project build for installation or deployment.
[INFO] Building zip: /home/user/jbpm5/target/jbpm-5.0.0-bin.zip
[INFO] Building zip: /home/user/jbpm5/target/jbpm-5.0.0-src.zip
[INFO] Building zip: /home/user/jbpm5/target/jbpm-5.0.0-gwt-console.zip
[INFO] Building zip: /home/user/jbpm5/target/jbpm-5.0.0-gwt-console.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive docs-build: You must set at least one file.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 minute 26 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 19 00:30:52 IST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/63M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[user@localhost jbpm5]$

please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message "Error creating assembly archive docs-build: You must set at least one file." it seems you didn't create the documentation, I'm guessing it needs to be -Ddocumentation instead of -DDocumentation.

Kris